# join query works from mysql but not from java

Tags: sql, spring-boot

I have a join query in my app. It's supposed to retrieve the students that don´t have a student account created yet. I thought the query worked until I wrote a unit test and there I noticed that the query is returning the same students even though the account was already created.

**The Query**

```
SELECT student_table.* FROM student student_table WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT app_relationship_table.student_id FROM relationship_table app_relationship_table WHERE student_table.student_id = app_relationship_table.student_id)
```

What I mean with the above query is: give all the students that exist in the students table but don't exist in the app_relationship_table that way I should know which students are missing their account. 
Funny thing is that this query works as it should in MySql Workbench but it doesn't work from my java code. It keeps giving me the same students that didn't have a student account in the beginning and thus creating duplicated data in the database.

I run the project from localhost. When I first run it, it works fine, but when I reload the page or do a scheduled task it would mess up and give me the same students even though the account is created and the relationship table updated with new foreign keys. I´m using `CrudRepository` to persist data

**Create student account code:**

```
@Override
    public void createStudentAccount(List<Student> studentsWithoutStudentAccount) {

        studentsWithoutStudentAccount.forEach(student->{

            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";

            StudentAccount studentAccount = new StudentAccount (username, password, student);
            save(studentAccount);

        });

    }
```

Anyone could help me? I don't know what I'm missing here

Comment: Are you sure you're re-executing the query/setting the `studentsWithoutStudentAccount` list data after the page reloads? Since it works the first time you go to the page

Comment: @Mark I just found out it´s a very wrong implementation problem. As I´m inserting the data in the database directly from the GetMapping method in the Controller class. Everything is getting reloaded from scratch every time the page is reloaded. I now this a different questions but otherwise, where would I put that method to fill the database with data without using data.sql? I'm new to Spring.

Comment: @Mark its fixed. Created the database from a class annotated with `@Component` and the method marked with `@PostConstruct`. The advantage is that the data will be loaded at startup without using data.sql so the relationship tables get created automatically.